# Como modificar o site sem ter que pedir um novo recurso?

Tags: suporte, design, api

Muitas vezes acho que o site ficaria melhor com determinado estilo ou organização de conteúdo, mas não é algo suficientemente importante como para fazer uma requisição de novo recurso. Quais são as alternativas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Que eu saiba o mais prático é fazer um ***Userscript***, que é uma extensão do navegador. Para gerenciar isso, no Firefox tem o [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) e no Chrome tem o [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) (parece que o Chrome tem [suporte nativo](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/userscripts/info) mas nunca testei).

O exemplo a seguir esconde o `#footer` da página com CSS e coloca um fundo amarelado nos comentários que foram editados com jQuery. Esses comentários já tem o ícone [image], mas, como edito meus comentários frequentemente, gosto de saber quem faz isso também e o ícone é imperceptível muitas vezes.

Atenção para o *escape* das quebras de linha na *string* do CSS [usando `\` no final exato](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4001/201) de cada linha.

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Meu custom Stack
// @match    *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match    *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match    *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match    *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match    *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match    *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match    *://*.superuser.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle("\
#footer { display:none; }\
");

/* roda em páginas que não são uma pergunta individual */
function allSite() {
    if (!window.StackExchange || window.StackExchange.options.user.isAnonymous )
        return;
    
    // fazer_algo_se_for_um_usuario_logado();
};

/* roda só quando vendo uma pergunta específica */
function singleQ() {
    if (!window.StackExchange)
        return;

    /* Destaca todos os comentários que foram editados */
    var do_it = function() {
        $('.comment-body').each(function(){
            if( $(this).find('span.edited-yes').length !== 0 )
                $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(236, 229, 220, 0.239216)');
        });
    }; 
    
    /* Repetir ao clicar em "mostrar mais comentários" */
    $('.js-show-link.comments-link').click(function(){
        setTimeout( do_it, 1000 );
    });
    
    do_it();
};

/* inserir script habilitando jQuery  / executa função callback (f) */
/* script de https://stackapps.com/q/2050 */
function with_jquery(f) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
};

/* detecta página atual */
function filter_so_check_page() {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var ok = true;
    if( path.indexOf('/questions') > -1 ) {
        var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' ); 
        if( pathArray[2] && !isNaN( parseInt( pathArray[2], 10 ) )  )
            ok = false;
    }
    return ok;
};

/* inicia o processo dependendo da página atual */
if( ( page = filter_so_check_page() ) !== false ) {
    with_jquery( allSite );
} else {
    with_jquery( singleQ );
}
```

<sub>[Lá no](https://stackapps.com/)</sub>

## [[image] Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/)

tem muita coisa legal.

Muitos exemplos, e é ponto obrigatório  para começar a trabalhar com a API do Stack Exchange.
<sub>Segue um exemplo de script que insere um novo recurso consultando a API: [*“View Vote totals” without 1000 rep*](https://stackapps.com/q/3082/10590).</sub>

Answer (score 4):

## Utilitários para alterar o *layout* e comportamento do site

Existem extensões de browser, como o [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) que permitem sobrepor o CSS de qualquer site. Para modificações mais profundas, ou com alvos específicos, precisamos de jQuery, e isso é obtido com userscripts, facilmente gerenciáveis com extensões como [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) e [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo).

### Adicionar underline aos links na páginas individuais de perguntas

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name    (SOPT) Personalizar CSS e comportamento dos links
// @match   *://*.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions*
// @grant   none
// ==/UserScript==

// Rodar somente quando vendo perguntas individuais
if( StackExchange.options.routeName === 'Questions/Show' ) {
    /* Adicionar underline nos links mostrados em posts e comentários */
    $('.post-text a, .comment-copy a').css('border-bottom','1px dotted #ccc')
    .mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css('border-bottom','0px')
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        $(this).css('border-bottom','1px dotted #ccc')
    });
}

/* Fazer com que links externos abram em nova janela */
/* Atenção que @match é só nas páginas abaixo de /questions */
$('a[href^="http"]')
    .not('a[href*="stackexchange"]')
    .not('a[href*="stackoverflow"]')
    .not('a[href*="superuser"]')
    .not('a[href*="serverfault"]')
    .not('a[href*="askubuntu"]')
    .not('a[href*="stackapps"]')
    .not('a[href*="mathoverflow"]')
    .attr('target','_blank');
```

<sup>[Instalar](https://gist.github.com/raw/a539c1905608b253fcb6/UnderlineEmLinks.user.js)</sup>

### Modificar o comportamento da tecla <kbd>Tab</kbd> ao editar posts

Userscript: [*Better handling of indentation and the TAB key when editing posts*](https://stackapps.com/questions/3247/better-handling-of-indentation-and-the-tab-key-when-editing-posts)

### Botão <kbd> no editor de texto

Userscript: [*<kbd> markup shortcuts*](https://stackapps.com/questions/3341/kbd-markup-shortcuts)

### Clicar para expandir blocos de código horizontal e verticalmente

Userscript: [*Click to expand code regions*](https://stackapps.com/questions/2574/click-to-expand-code-regions)

### Comentários aninhados

Userscript: [*Threaded comments*](https://stackapps.com/questions/2050/threaded-comments)

### Shortcodes (magic links) personalizados para comentários

Extensão para Chrome: [*Stack Exchange comment's shortcodes*](https://github.com/brasofilo/WPA-shortcodes)

Extensão para Chrome, FF e userscript: [*AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE*](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)

### Desabilitar <kbd>Enter</kbd> nos comentários

Userscript: [*Disable enter for submitting comments*](https://stackapps.com/questions/2061/disable-enter-for-submitting-comments)

### Habilitar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Bold, Itálico, Código e Link em comentários

Userscript: [*Add keyboard shortcuts to comments*](https://stackapps.com/questions/2103/add-keyboard-shortcuts-to-comments)

### Personalizar o menu Ajuda na topbar

Userscript: [*Turbocharged Help Menu*](https://stackapps.com/questions/4921/turbocharged-help-menu)

### StackOverflow CodeBox Options

Userscript: [*expand code box, resize font, widen the entire page*](https://stackapps.com/questions/8013/stackoverflow-codebox-options)

### Bookmarklet para gerar link de pergunta em markdown

```
javascript:(function(){ var result='['+document.title+']('+document.URL+')'; window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", result); })();
```

<sup>**Fonte:** [Add markdown quick-links to the share dialog?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232107/add-markdown-quick-links-to-the-share-dialog/239362#239362)</sup>

Comment: @bfavaretto, good catch, jjjj. Tem um erro na minha lógica ali do `$('a[href^="http://"]')`, sabe porquê?

Comment: Parece certo aquilo, só não vai funcionar pra https.

Comment: Ah, não funciona também se os links forem tipo `/q/123`, ou seja, se no href não houver uma url completa, com protocolo, domínio e tal. Será esse o bug?

Comment: Não tenho certeza se eram as aspas, mas modifiquei também só pra `^=http` e parece estar funcionando bem. Acho que o `/q/123` não importa. Vlw!

Comment: Não estou achando sua bookmarklet para gerar links de perguntas, será que cabe aqui mesmo não sendo userscript?

Comment: Depois atualizo a resposta (ou se quiseres), o bookmarklet táqui [Add markdown quick-links to the share dialog?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239362/185667) e lá tem o link pra um outro script meu que ficou bem bão

Comment: Incluí, mas não sei se está num bom formato. Valeu, eu estava procurando no MSOpt, nunca ia encontrar!

Comment: Bom formato:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/fnxQc.gif :)

Answer (score 3):

Criei um layout mais minimalista e **redondo** para o SOpt e o SOpt-meta. O código afeta praticamente tudo no site, arredondando e tirando o contraste das cores, focando mais no conteúdo.

Inspirado no Material Design.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código para aplicar no [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo):

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name    (SOPT) Rounded UI em todo lugar
// @match   *://*.pt.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match   *://*.pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @grant   none
// ==/UserScript==

/* Ícone dos usuários */
$('.bar-sm')
   .attr('style', 'border-radius: 3000px !important')
   .removeClass("bar-sm");

/* Barra de pesquisa */
$('input[name="q"]')
   .css('border-radius', '3000px')
   .css('border-color', 'Gainsboro');

/* Caixa de código branca e redonda */
$('pre')
   .css('border', '1px solid Gainsboro')
   .css('border-radius', '10px')
   .css('border-color', 'Gainsboro');

$('pre, code')
   .css('background-color', 'white');

/* Remove a barra laranja do topo */
$('.top-bar')
   .css('background-color', 'white')
   .css('border', 'none');

/* Widget amarelo */
$('.s-sidebarwidget')
   .css('position', 'inherit')
   .css('border', '');

$('.s-sidebarwidget__yellow, .s-sidebarwidget')
   .css('border-color', 'Gainsboro')
   .css('border-radius', '10px')
   .css('background-color', 'white');

$('.s-sidebarwidget--header')
   .css('border-color', 'Gainsboro')
   .css('border-radius', '10px')
   .css('background-color', 'white');

$('.s-sidebarwidget--content')
    .css('border-color', 'Gainsboro');

$('.s-sidebarwidget__small-bold-text')
    .removeClass('s-sidebarwidget__small-bold-text');

$('.s-notice')
    .css('border-radius', '10px')
    .addClass('shadow');

$('.s-btn__primary')
    .css('box-shadow', 'none')
    .css('border-radius', '80px');

$('a', $('.s-btn-group')).each(function () {
    $(this)
        .css('border', 'none')
        .css('margin-right', '8px');

    if(! $(this).hasClass('is-selected')) {
        $(this).css('border-radius', '10px');
    } else {
        $(this).css('border-radius', '8px 8px 0px 0px');
    }
});

$('#qlist-wrapper')
    .css('border-top', 'none');

$('.is-selected')
    .css('border-bottom', '2px solid blue')
    .css('background-color', 'white');

$('.post-signature, .s-card')
    .css('border-radius', '10px');

$('.question-summary')
    .css('border-radius', '10px')
    .css('border-bottom', 'none');

$('blockquote')
    .css('background-color', 'transparent')
    .css('border-left', '4px solid #c8ccd0')
    .css('border-radius', '4px');

$('body')
    .css('background-color', 'white');

$('#content')
    .css('border', 'none');
```

Answer (score 1):

tem este também: https://stackapps.com/questions/8013/stackoverflow-codebox-options

[image: options-menu]

Comment: Não precisa de uma nova resposta, edita a da brasofilo que já é uma resposta do tipo Wiki, do qual qualquer um pode editar.